How to Enforce Compile-Time Errors for Non-.NET Standard Assemblies in a .NET Standard Project?
I'm migrating several projects from .NET Framework to .NET Standard 2.0. As part of this migration, I need to ensure that all project references assemblies that are compatible with .NET Standard. However, I’ve encountered an issue where references to non-.NET Standard assemblies produce runtime exceptions but there aren't any compile-time warnings or errors.
Let's look at one example. Li1.csproj is written in .net framework 4.8 and is not compatible with .netstandard2.0.
There is a compile-time warning in case of a ProjectReference
<ProjectReference Include="Lib1" />

NU1702  ProjectReference 'Lib1.csproj' was resolved using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This project may not be fully compatible with your project.

If we use an assembly reference, there aren't any compile errors but a runtime error is raised that the assembly cannot be loaded.
<Reference Include="Lib1">
  <HintPath>..\Lib1\bin\$(Configuration)\Lib1.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

How can I configure my .NET Standard project to produce a compile-time error if a referenced assembly is not compatible with .NET Standard? Is there a way to automatically enforce this check across all projects during the build process?
I've tried using some common tools like Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers and ApiPort, but they don't seem to address this specific issue.

solution: package references instead of assembly references; the entire point of packages is to have that additional context (and potentially support for multiple targets in the same logical unit)

Unfortunately we have 100+ solutions and it's impossible to migrate from assembly references to package references.

It absolutely is not impossible; you just don't want to invest the effort to do it; but: that is the ideal solution to this scenario. If you don't like that solution for your set of local requirements: that's fine - I can respect that - but then you need to accept the negatives of that choice, or find a third option.

You could write a Roslyn analyzer for this. The full compatibility checking might get a bit tricky, but rejecting stuff that clearly depends on .NET Framework might be easy enough.

There is a .NET Portability Analyzer for VS 2017 and VS 2019 that may help.
